# Как включить в процедуре dbms_output?

Tags: oracle, plsql, процедуры

Есть пакет и в нем процедура. В ней хочу использовать команду:

```
dbms_output.put_line('some text');
```

Где нужно размещать команду `set serveroutput on`, чтобы включить вывод?

Пробовал внутри тела процедуры, но не работает, получаю ошибку:

> Error(5,9): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored

Comment: Перед запуском процедуры.

Comment: @0xdb но тогда пакет не компилируется с ошибкой PLS-00201: идентификатор 'DBMB_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE' должен быть объявлен

Comment: Странно, в вопросе вы указали - `dbms_output.put_line('some text');`, а в ошибке - `DBMB_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE`. Вы разницу не видите?

Comment: @0xdb верно, проглядел опечатку. Поставил ...on перед вызовом - заработало, спасибо.

Comment: Рад был помочь! Если вы планируете в дальнейшем задавать вопросы, то могу дать более подробный ответ, чтобы дать вам возможность заработать репутацию.

Comment: @0xdb буду спрашивать еще, но репутация меня не очень интересует

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[SET](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqpug/SET.html#GUID-9095C4FF-F4EB-4218-84AA-83061186625F) это команда клиентского приложения, которая устанавливает его внутреннею системную переменную [SERVEROUTPUT {ON|OFF}](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqpug/SET-system-variable-summary.html#GUID-5EA17047-1EBC-44BA-A21A-B4CEC27FD6B0). Эту команду поддерживат: SQL*Plus, SQL Developer и некоторые другие, но она *не является частью синтаксиса* PL/SQL или SQL.
Её надо выполнить *до запуска* PL/SQL блока:

```
create or replace procedure proc is
begin 
    dbms_output.put_line ('line 1'); 
    dbms_output.put_line ('line 2'); 
end;
/
set serveroutput on
exec proc

line 1
line 2
```

Что делает `SET SERVEROUTPUT ON` "под капотом", поможет понять следующий пример.
Отключим вывод, сбросив пременную `SERVEROUTPUT OFF`, и выполним всё, что делалось неявно с `SERVEROUTPUT ON`, теперь вручную. Сначала, заново включим вывод:

```
set serveroutput off     

exec dbms_output.enable ();
```

Запустим процедуру:

```
exec proc

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Во время выполнения процедуры, каждый вызов `dbms_output.put_line('some text');` будет добавлять одну строчку во внутренний массив строк, который сохраняется в области переменных сессии. *Никакого вывода на консоль не будет*, ни во время выполнения, ни после завершения. Это задача клиента - получить содержимое внутреннего массив строк и вывести его на консоль. Это выглядит как-то так:

```
var output varchar2
declare
    lines dbms_output.CHARARR; 
    nl int := 100;
begin 
    dbms_output.get_lines (lines, nl); 
    for i in 1..nl loop
        :output := :output||lines(i)||chr(10);
    end loop;
end;
/
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

print output 

line 1
line 2
```